# Why web frameworks should be hosted on web servers?

Tags: nginx, django, framework

I just started in the hosting world, and something that I haven't been able to fully understand is why web frameworks need to be hosted in web servers?

Recently I had a website runing over django, and thanks to some python scripts like dj-static and static I was able to serve the static files. So why is the need of using a web server?

After some days of coding, I wanted to enable https and I read that I needed to use a web server, but after some more research I found a post about someone who said being able of using https without a web server. So again, why are web servers necessary?

Is it a security reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The builtin web servers of Django and co are very minimal pieces of software, they are optimized to make development/debugging easy but they don't care about performance, security or features.

As developing a secure and performant web server is quite difficult, it would be quite nonsensical for a web framework to invest any time into this while the problem is already solved by 3rd parties.

Comment: And putting them inside a web framework improves the performance? ( I guess that for the security and features its normal). So in a few words, if django security and features are okay for me there no real reason of using a web framework?

Comment: The security of e.g. the Django dev web server is *not* okay for any production use. It's a dev tool, nothing else.

Comment: When you say "It's a dev tool, nothing else." it confuses me, isn't okey to use for example nginx + django for a production server?

Comment: I mean just the builtin web server that Django offers for developing/testing. It's not a viable solution to run a django app in production, but nginx+uwsgi certainly are.